# Timeseries vocabulary: interval vs instant-referenced

Tags: time-series, terminology

In geostatistics a difference is made between *point-referenced*
observations and *areal observations*. In the first case, an
observation is related to a specific location such as a node in an
observation grid. In the second case an observation is related to a
geographical area: country, district, county, ... This vocabulary
seems to be consistently used in several classical books.

For timeseries, a similar distinction applies: an observation can
either refer to as specific time or be related to a time-interval: a
specific minute, day, month, year, ...  This distinction is of major
importance both for data management and for statistical modelling. In
relation with a possible continuous-time model, time-interval
observations result from a mechanism of aggregation which imports much
and is not necessarily an integration over time: it can instead be
taking the maximum in time. The difference between the two types of
timeseries can be related to that between *flow* and *stock* variables
in econometry, but this terminology does not seem to be common in
other fields such as physics or meteorology.

What vocabulary should best be used to make a distinction between the
two types of timeseries above?

Comment: It's a good question, but the issue is rarely important because the data supports tend to have the same sizes in the time series application and the change of support problem is relatively straightforward to handle.

Comment: Thank you.  "change of support" is an interesting keyword for investigations on this topic.